# Stubbing tomorrow's date in rspec

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a method in which am sending tomorrow's date(1.date.from_now). I'm testing the same method in my specs. Can anyone tell me how to stub that date.

if I pass 1.date.from now. am getting following error.

```
   <S3Client (class)> received :upload_csv_by_path with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("/home/projects/sh/tmp/test_exporter.csv", nil, {:expires=>Sat, 07 Feb 2015 11:36:39 UTC +00:00})
          got: ("/home/projects/sh/tmp/test_exporter.csv", nil, {:expires=>Sat, 07 Feb 2015 11:36:39 UTC +00:00})
```

below is my method

```
S3Client.upload_csv_by_path(file_name, nil, expires: 1.day.from_now)
```

Here is my spec,

```
S3Client.should_receive(:upload_csv_by_path).with("#{Rails.root}/tmp/scalar_test_exporter.csv", nil, expires: 1.day.from_now)
```

Can anyone tell me how can i solve this issue

Comment: look at gem [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the times might look exactly the same, but the timestamps aren't, the time which is spent between running the two statements ( even if it's in micro seconds ) makes the time different, to solve it you should use the same time variable in both statements, for example:

```
time = Time.now
S3Client.should_receive(:upload_csv_by_path).with("#{Rails.root}/tmp/scalar_test_exporter.csv", nil, expires: time)
S3Client.upload_csv_by_path(file_name, nil, expires: time)
```

This way you could make sure that the time is the same in both statements, or you could use a gem like [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to help you with this like @gotva suggested, timecop is very useful because it gives you the ability to freeze time, move forward and backwards in time, it's nice, for the same example you'd write this

```
Time.freeze
S3Client.should_receive(:upload_csv_by_path).with("#{Rails.root}/tmp/scalar_test_exporter.csv", nil, expires: 1.day.from_now)
S3Client.upload_csv_by_path(file_name, nil, expires: 1.day.from_now)
Time.return
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by  using Time.now + 1.day in my method.

and stubbed the Time.now and while passing parameter added 1day as below.

```
current_time = Time.now
Time.stub(:now) { current_time }
S3Client.should_receive(:upload_csv_by_path).with("#{Rails.root}/tmp/scalar_test_exporter.csv", nil, expires: current_time + 1.day)
```